# How do I read a file exclusively in perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a perl module that my library of collecting scripts use. These scripts are for scanning my network, doing various tasks on my network devices, etc.

there are about `15 users` and I only want `1` person at a time to run a collecting script. if a second user tries to run the script, then I want them to wait until the first person is finished.

The code below is just a test bed, so i can get it working correctly before i put it into production. I have a module that has a `nap` function. I only want one person to nap at a time.

```
sub nap {
        my $program = shift;
        my @arr;

        #open file to check the queue
        open(IN, $path); @arr=<IN>; close IN;

        #if someone is in the queue, print it out!
        $|++;
        if (@arr > 0) { print @arr; }

        #keep checking the queue, once the queue is empty it's my turn!
        while (@arr != 0) {
                open(IN, $path); @arr=<IN>; close IN;
                sleep 1;
        }

        #it's my turn, put my name in the queue
        open(IN,">",$path);
        print IN "$ENV{USER},$program";
        close IN;

        #take a nap!
        print "\n Sleep starting \n";
        sleep 10;

        #I'm finished with my nap, clear the queue so other's can go
        open(IN,">",$path);
        close IN;
        print "\nsleep over\n";
}
```

my issue is it works if `1 user` is waiting, but if `2 users` are waiting, they both still take a nap at the same time ( after the first user finishes )

can I lock or block this file? I've seen `flock` but it appears no matter how you lock it, the user can still read.

is this even a correct solution? or is there something better used for these purposes?

Comment: On Unix, this is by design.  All locks are advisory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock the DATA section of a file to lock the file itself, so you can (ab)use that to control exclusive access to that script.

I put this in a library file `nap.pl`:

```
#!usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use Fcntl qw(LOCK_EX LOCK_NB);

sub nap {
    ## make sure this script only runs one copy of itself
    until ( flock DATA, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) {
        print "someone else has a lock\n";
        sleep 5;
    }
}

__DATA__
This exists to allow the locking code at the beginning of the file to work.
DO NOT REMOVE THESE LINES!
```

Then I opened 3 terminals and ran this in each one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
do 'nap.pl';

&nap;
print `ls /tmp/`;
sleep 5;
```

The first terminal printed the contents of my /tmp directory immediately.
The second terminal printed "someone else has a lock" and then after 5 seconds, it printed the contents of /tmp.
The third terminal printed "someone else has a lock" *twice*, once immediately and then once after 5 seconds, and then printed the contents of /tmp/.

Be careful about where you put this in your library though, you'd want to make sure that things aren't locking unrelated subroutines.

I would personally put the lock code in each *collecting* script, not in the library.  The collecting script is what you're actually trying to only run one instance of.  It seems your title isn't accurate: you're not trying to exclusively *read* a file, you're trying to exclusively *run* a file.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, few questions can you explain this line? `until ( flock DATA, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) `  why use `|` instead of `||` 


also, I was thinking the lock in the library would be the best bet. I have many different scripts that use the same library, collecting diagnostics, collecting interface status, checking compliancy, etc. that I still want only one of the scripts to run at the same time. ( to lessen resource use, ssh sessions). do you thin I should lock in the running script only?

Comment: You need `LOCK_EX` to take an exclusive lock.  The `LOCK_NB` returns control to your program so you can `print` what's going on, otherwise it would hang waiting for the lock.  You use `|` instead of `||` because `|` is a bitwise operator i.e. `LOCK_EX` = 2, `LOCK_NB` = 4, `LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB`=6

Comment: If your goal is really to only have *one* collecting script run _at all_, then locking the library is fine.  If you have collecting scripts of `foo` and `bar` and want to make sure that only one copy of `foo` runs but it shouldn't interfere with someone running `bar`, then you should put locking code in `foo` and `bar`.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is not correct. For one thing, you're using plain `open`, which buffers reads and writes, which causes complications when you want several processes to communicate via one file.

As you seem to already suspect, and as others have commented, there is no (reasonable) way on a Unixlike operating system to forcibly make it so that only one process can read from a file. The in some sense correct way to handle it is to use a lock file, and only have the process currently holding the lock read from the data/communication file. Check `perldoc -f flock` for details on that.

File locks on Unix does have some drawbacks, unfortunately. Particularly if the lock file resides on a network filesystem they can be unreliable. With NFS, for example, functional locks depend on all machines mounting the filesystem having a lock daemon running. One somewhat hacky but traditional way to work around this is to abuse the semantics of `mkdir`. If a bunch of processes all try to create a directory with the same name, it is guaranteed that only one of them will succeed (well, or none, but let's skip that for now). You can use that for synchronizing the processes. Before a process starts doing the thing that only one at a time should be doing, it tries to create a directory with a pre-determined name. If it succeeds, fine, it can go on. If it fails, someone else is already working and it has to wait. When the active process is done working, it removes the directory so another process can then succeed in creating it.

Anyway, the basic message is that you need two filesystem thingies: one that your processes use to determine which one of them may work, and one for the actual work.

Comment: Re "you're using plain `open`, which buffers reads and writes", No, `open` doesn't read or write (buffered or otherwise).`read`, `readline` and `eof` are buffered reads. `sysread` isn't.  All writes are buffered by default (except those to STDERR).

Comment: Several Unix-likes have mandatory locking support (including of regions of a file) originated in SysV. For instance, on Linux, if you mount a FS with `-o mand` and change the permissions of a file with `chmod g+s-x`, then you can use `fcntl(F_SETLK)` to lock a region of a file. [Use of that is generally discouraged though at least on Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.